# FIREBASE_MESSAGING: onBackgroundMessage not handling notification when app is on Background or Terminated

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm trying to get my onBackgroundMessage to execute when the app is on Background and a notification has been receive, but it doesn't execute myBackgroundMessageHandler.

I did everything that was written in the documentation at Optionally handle background messages, but it still doesn't work like i want,
When i receive a notification when the app is on Background, What i get is a notification without data (no app icon and no images, only title and body text).Btw it's working well when the app is not onBackground

Here my code :

```
AndroidManifest.xml

<application
        android:name=".Application"
```

**index.js**

```
  message = {
    android: {
        notification: { click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',}
    },
    token: androidNotificationToken,
    data: {
      activityFeedItemId:activityFeedItemId,
      userReceivingNotificationId: userId,
      userActivatingNotificationPhotoUrl: activityFeedItem.userProfileImg,
      notificationType: activityFeedItem.type,
      body : body
    }
  };
```

**buildgradle**

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.7'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.yimerah.ijn_amen;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.yimerah.ijn_amen;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

**OnBackgroundMessage**

```
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
   static myBackgroundMessageHandler{
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await auth.currentUser();

    print("on message:$message\n");
    final String userReceivingId =
        message['data']['userReceivingNotificationId'];
    final String body = message['data']['body'];
    final String notificationType = message['data']['notificationType'];
    final String notificationId = message['data']['activityFeedItemId'];
    if (userReceivingId == firebaseUser.uid) {
      int id = Uuid().parse(notificationId).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        final String notificationMedia =
            message['data']['userActivatingNotificationPhotoUrl'];
        await showNotificationMediaStyle("", body, notificationMedia, id: id);


      print("Notification shown!");
    }
    print("Notification not shown!");
  }
```

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When constructing a data notification, the `notification` payload MUST be blank.

If the `notification` payload is not empty, then the payload will be sent as a notification instead of a data message.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working . I also had to remove the if statement (userReceivingId == firebaseUser.uid) from the backgroundMessageHandler because when the app is onBackground it cannot get the firebaseUser.uid, hence handle the background message data..

Comment: @ray-li can you please share us the sample payload

Comment: which payload are you referring to, please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior when the app is in the background, the notification goes directly to the Sytem Tray without `onMessageReceived` being called

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: So i had to implement onMessageReceived ? but how ? The doc doesn't seem to be adapted to flutter...

Comment: Even if the method is called onBackgroundMessage or onMessageReceived that document says that the method will not be called if the app is in the background.

Comment: Then what ? does this mean that it's not possible to handle notification in the background ?

Comment: Yes, the notification goes directly to the System Tray.

Answer (score 0):

With the onBackgroundMessage function from Firebase/Flutter you are only able to print a message or use Flutter Local Notifications to show the message.

If you want to do anything else, like update app state, or make API request, this is not immediately available.

I won't give the full coded answer, but the fix is to use Dart Isolates and Isolate communication. Please do your own research here, but it is easy to implement.

The reason for this is because the Firebase background handler runs on a separate isolate that doesn't have access to the Flutter app isolate and memory.